# Append printf statement then add to it

Tags: c, string, append, concatenation

Is there any way to append printf statements together then finish adding my values into it at the end? For example, I have a for loop that keeps printing statements then I have:

```
printf("%d units(1) %d units(2) units(3) units(4)",unitOne,unitTwo);
```

It's kinda hard to explain, but basically im supposed to print unitThree and unitFour but I can't print them because I calculated them below the code that prints the print statement and I need the print statement there because it depends on a loop.

Comment: Could You please try clarifying with input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go back in printing: once something is printed, there is no general way to go back and insert stuff in front of it.

The trick to solving issues like yours is to prepare the data upfront in the first loop, and then use a second loop to print the data. This way the orders in which you produce the data and the order in which you print it become independent of each other.

```
int units[MAX_UNIT];
for (int i = 0 ; i != MAX_UNIT ; i++) {
    // fill units with data
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != MAX_UNIT ; i += 4) {
    printf("%d units(1) %d units(2) %d units(3) %d units(4)",
           units[i], units[i+1], units[i+2], units[i+3]);
}
```

Comment: let's hope `MAX_UNIT` is a multiple of 4 `;-)`